# Multithread debugging techniques

Tags: .net, multithreading, debugging

I was wondering if anyone knows of a nice survey of debugging techniques for multithreaded applications. Ideally, I'm looking for a case-based analysis: deadlocks, starvation, corrupted shared state, ...

.Net specific, or generic.

Comment: There are lots of cool tools out there, but don't overlook the simple approach of just reading through the code. I've been doing multithreaded debugging for years, and it's one of the most effective methods.

Comment: True. That works pretty well. I'm looking more at techniques ('like' this) than tools.

Comment: +1 @Stephen Very true indeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not aware of an article or book that addresses what you're looking for, so here's my "lessons learned" from 12 years of multithreaded debugging on Windows (both unmanaged and managed).

As I stated in my comment, most of my "multithreaded debugging" is actually done via a manual code review, looking for these issues.

**Deadlocks and Corrupted Shared State**

Document [lock hierarchies](http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/204801163) (both the order and what shared state they protect), and ensure they're consistent. This solves most deadlock problems and corrupted shared state problems.

(Note: the link above for "lock hierarchies" refers to a Dr. Dobbs article by Herb Sutter; he's written a whole series of [Effective Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/bb895974.aspx) articles that I highly recommend).

**More on Deadlocks**

Use [RAII for all synchronization](http://www.parkscomputing.com/code/threading.aspx). This ensures that locks are released in the face of exceptions. Prefer the "lock" statement to try/finally.

(Note that RAII in .NET depends on `IDisposable`, not `Finalize`, and assumes that the client code will correctly use a `using` block).

**Starvation**

Remove any modifications of thread priorities. Correct prioritization is actually a bit counter-intuitive: it is best to give the thread with the most work to do a lower priority, and give higher priorities to threads that are I/O bound (including the UI thread). Since Windows does this automatically (see [Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301)), there's really no reason for the code to get involved at all.

**In General**

Remove all lock-free code that was written in-house. It almost certainly contains subtle bugs. Replace it with .NET 4 [lock-free collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) and [synchronization objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xyf641a.aspx), or change the code to be lock-based.

Use higher-level concepts for synchronization. The [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and [unified cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) in .NET 4 remove pretty much any need for direct usage of `ManualResetEvent`, `Monitor`, `Semaphore`, etc.

Use higher-level concepts for parallelization. The [TPL and PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx) in .NET 4 have built-in self-balancing algorithms complete with intelligent partitioning and work-stealing queues to provide optimum parallelization automatically. For the few rare cases that the automatic parallelization is sub-optimal, both TPL and PLINQ expose a huge number of tweakable knobs (custom partitioning schemes, long-running operation flags, etc).

There is one more technique I've found useful for any class that has its methods called by different threads: document which methods run on which threads. Usually, this is added as a comment to the top of the method. Ensure each method only runs in a known thread context (e.g., "on a UI thread" or "on a ThreadPool thread" or "on the dedicated background thread"). None of the methods should say "on any thread" unless you're writing a synchronization class (and if you're writing a synchronization class, ask yourself if you really should be doing that).

Lastly, name your threads. This helps easily distinguish them when using the VS debugger. .NET supports this via the `Thread.Name` property.

Answer (score 6):

Not what you are asking for but maybe you find [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/) interesting.

Comment: +1 for ... awesomeness. had no idea such a thing existed! viva CHESS!

Comment: In theory it is seriously awesome, but I have not personally had much luck with it in practice. It just didn't detect issues where I was trying to diagnose existing MT problems, so it was pretty much a fail.

Comment: This is now part of VS2010, is it not?

Comment: As far as I know VS2010 contains new tools/features for parallel debugging but I don't know if Chess or a subset of Chess is included.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at Intel's [Thread Checker](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-thread-checker/) or [Thread Profiler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/) and [Sun's Studio Thread Analyzer](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/downloads/ssx/tha/tha_getting_started.html), though they are not free. Also check out [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/multi-threading-in-the-net-environment/) article from Intel.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Helgrind a subtool of Valgrind. Helgrind is a thread error detector and I've used it once or twice to detect race conditions in some of my code. It can detect the following things.

1. Misuses of the POSIX pthreads API.
2. Potential deadlocks arising from lock ordering problems.
3. Data races -- accessing memory without adequate locking or synchronisation.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html

Obviously only linux tool for system programs, C / C++.  No Java or .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any technique can reliably detect all multithreading problems, because the code causing them is just too complicated to analyse. No tool can detect such problems in real time neither, because the tool itself needs also time to run. The program to debug would behave completely different with the tool and without.

I had to debug real time problems which occured in production only once a month ! The only solution I found is to add code detecting that problem and to write trace information by the threads involved. Of course, the tracing must be EXTREMELY fast and non blocking. Usual tools like Visual Studio are way too slow for real time tracing, but luckily, it is easy to write your own memory trace:

```
const int maxMessages = 0x100;
const int indexMask = maxMessages-1;
string[] messages = new string[maxMessages];
int messagesIndex = -1;

public void Trace(string message) {
  int thisIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref messagesIndex) & indexMask;
  messages[thisIndex] = message;
}
```

A more detailed description for this approach which also collects thread and timing information and outputs the trace nicely is at:
CodeProject: Debugging multithreaded code in real time [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792532/Debugging-multithreaded-code-in-real-time)